# MongoDB: Update just one object of nested arrays

Tags: mongodb

I want to change the third `data` element of the second element of `group`

```
{
    "_id" : "wLXDvjDvbsxzfxabR",
    "group" : [
        {
            "title" : "title 1",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "note" : "text"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title" : "title 2",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "note 1" : "text"
                },
                {
                    "note 2" : "text"
                },
                {
                    "note 3" : "text"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I'm doing, but it gives me a wrong result:

```
var setObject = { group.2.data.3: { 'new note': 'new text'} }

Collection.update(
    { _id: 'wLXDvjDvbsxzfxabR' }, 
    { $set: setObject }
);
```

By this a new element is added to the group - which is NOT what I want:

```
    {
        "data" : {
            "3": {
                "note" : "text"
            }
        }
    }
```

I just want to set/update the object `{ "note 3": "text" }` to `{ 'new note': 'new text'}` and keep the structure like it is.

**Result should be**

```
{
    "_id" : "wLXDvjDvbsxzfxabR",
    "group" : [
        {
            "title" : "title 1",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "note" : "text"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title" : "title 2",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "note 1" : "text"
                },
                {
                    "note 2" : "text"
                },
                {
                    "new note" : "new text"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are zero-indexed, so:

```
var setObject = { 'group.1.data.2': { 'new note': 'new text'} }
```

As [Mongodb's doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) says:

> To access an element of an array by the **zero-based index position**,
>   concatenate the array name with the dot (.) and zero-based index
>   position, and **enclose in quotes**:

```
'<array>.<index>'
```